# Swift doesn't recognize method from Obj-C class

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm working in Swift 3, taking pieces of a similar app that builds and runs under Swift 2.3 Xcode 7.  We are developing a new app with some of the same functionality.  Some of this is in an external library.

In the 2.3 project, I have a file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <UIKit/UIImage.h>

@interface MMOCR : NSObject {

}

-(NSString*) doOCRAtImage:(UIImage*)scannedImage;

@end
```

That file is included in the bridging header file, and it compiles and runs.  This is the code:

```
 let mmocr = MMOCR()
 result = mmocr.doOCRAtImage(croppedImage)
```

But in my new project, I'm getting this:

'doOCRAtImage' has been renamed to 'do(at:)'

So it recognizes the class, but not the method.  Is this a change from 2.3 to 3?  I haven't yet converted and compiled the old project, so I don't know if this compiles under 3 and Xcode 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does recognize your method, but it's applying Swift 3's new naming conventions. So, when you call this Objective-C method, you simply want to follow the guidance of that error message and call it as `do(at:)`:

```
result = mmocr.do(at: croppedImage)
```

For more information, see [SE-0005: Better Translation of Objective-C APIs Into Swift](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0005-objective-c-name-translation.md) or WWDC 2016 video [Swift API Design Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/403/).

---

By the way, if you can edit the `@interface` (i.e. if `MMOCR` was your own class), you can override the Swift name with `NS_SWIFT_NAME`:

```
- (NSString*) doOCRAtImage:(UIImage *)scannedImage NS_SWIFT_NAME(doOCR(at:));
```

Then, you'd do:

```
let result = mmocr.doOCR(at: croppedImage)
```

---

Personally, if `MMOCR` was your own class, I might be tempted to rename `doOCRAtImage:` entirely, perhaps to something like:

```
- (NSString*) recognizeTextInImage:(UIImage *)scannedImage;
```

Then, the Swift 3 code would be:

```
result = mmocr.recognizeText(in: croppedImage)
```

This is a more dramatic change than just using `NS_SWIFT_NAME`, but it might yield more intuitive code in both Objective-C and Swift 3.

---

If this `MMOCR` is a third-party library that you can't easily modify, you can always define your own extension to provide this method an alternative, more logical name, e.g.:

```
extension MMOCR {
    func recognizeText(in image: UIImage) -> String {
        return self.do(at: image)
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```
result = mmocr.recognizeText(in: croppedImage)
```

Obviously, feel free to chose whatever name you want. But this way, you can use this more logical name throughout your code rather than the cryptic `do(at:)` syntax.

Personally, I'd submit an enhancement request to the provider of this `MMOCR` class, asking them to provide a more logical Swift 3 interface (either with `NS_SWIFT_NAME` or by renaming the method), but the extension is a way to have an elegant interface with their API until such time that they revisit this themselves.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, life.  Thanks for the response, this was it exactly.  But am I missing something here?  The language/compiler is dictating to me what I can and cannot name my functions?  In this case this is a library we are using.  I'm new to the project, so I'm not sure where it comes from, but we don't have source.  So I can't change the actual names of the functions.   So Swift feels free to make this a compile time error instead of a warning?  I hope that I am missing something here...

Comment: The compiler is not, technically, dictating the name of your methods. The API authors can call them what they want. It is, though, dictating how Objective-C names are rendered in Swift 3. And if the API follows established conventions, it generally results in concise and expressive Swift syntax. (In fact, Apple has long explicitly discouraged the use of `do` in method names because "these auxilliary verbs rarely add meaning.") Unfortunately, that API you're using has poor names, so you're stuck with that awkward `do(at:)` syntax in the absence of the `NS_SWIFT_NAME` qualifier.

Comment: Yes, I see what you are saying.  I used the named the methods with NS_SWIFT_NAME and am calling it good.  It still seems too controlling to me, I would prefer this was a warning and not an error.  Thanks for your responses, it has helped a lot!